# Header missing at marshalling a sql result to csv

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I got this route in camel:

```
    <route id="route-sql">
        <from uri="file://data/sqlin?delay=1000&amp;include=.*\.sql$&amp;charset=utf-8" />

        <to uri="jdbc:datasourcePdm" />
        <marshal>
            <csv delimiter="&#x9;"  quoteDisabled="true" ></csv>
        </marshal>
        <to uri="file://data/sqlout"/>
    </route>
```

It works and the data is written in csv-format but there is no header in the first line. Also the 'quoting-behaviour' is some kind of strange - not all data cells are quoted. I tried some options indicated here http://camel.apache.org/csv.html but with no luck.

I am using  artifactId 'camel-csv' with version 2.15.1 in my pom.xml.

My questions:
1. how to add a header row to the csv-file
2. how to quote all data cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using CsvDataFormat and set headers, http://camel.apache.org/csv.html

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start")
                .log("${body}")
                .marshal(new org.apache.camel.dataformat.csv.CsvDataFormat().setHeader(new String[]{"foo", "bar"}))
                .log("${body}")
                ;
        }
    });

    template.sendBody("direct:start", new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(){{
        put("foo", "abc");
        put("bar", 123);
    }});
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

Haven't tried the following but it should work I guess

```
<bean id="myCsv" class="org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.CsvDataFormat">
  <property name="delimeter" value="&#x9;"/>
  <property name="quoteDisabled" value="true"/>
  <property name="headers">
    <list>
      <value>a</value>
      <value>b</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<route id="route-sql">
  <from uri="file://data/sqlin?delay=1000&amp;include=.*\.sql$&amp;charset=utf-8"/>

  <to uri="jdbc:datasourcePdm"/>
  <marshal ref="myCsv"/>
  <to uri="file://data/sqlout"/>
</route>
```

Comment: This seems to be a hard-coded list. I want to support answers to sql queries. So the header has to be dynamic depending on the sql query. Can i use the header attribute CamelJdbcColumnNames to make it more flexible?

Comment: Yes you could, you could aggregate the headers togheter with the rest of the data http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html

Comment: I am a little bit disappointed that this 'simple' task is that complicated. So i decided to write my own processor to solve the issue. thx for your time.